# How do I revoke access to twitter for a single app on iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

I sometimes let my kid (6 years old) use my IPhone 4s (iOS 6.1.3) to play angry birds.
Lately friends have been telling me that I tweet silly angry-bird tweets.

It seems that the Angry Birds application uses iOS integration to tweet in my name, and makes it very easy for my son to make those tweets.

I would like to block this application from sending tweets in my name, but I would rather not log out entirely from twitter on my IPhone.

All I could find on the matter is [here](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20169494#revoke-access-via-web), which claims that I would need to revoke access to the entire iOS integration:

> **Note:** Though you will see other specific apps like Twitter for iPhone or Camera for iOS listed in your active connections, you cannot revoke access to these individual apps; **you have to revoke the entire iOS integration**

That doesn't sound right - by allowing one app to integrate with twitter, I allow any app to do so? Is there no another way?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of iOS and Phone do you use? (Edit: or your son ;D )

Comment: iOS 6.1.3 on IPhone 4s

Comment: Sorry about my incorrect answer. I was quite sure it was listed there (it at least should be if it uses the iOS<->Twitter integration

Comment: I agree it sounded reasonable enough. This is very frustrating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reply from Rovio, maker of the game:

> This feature has been done in cooperation with Twitter Inc. Thus, players of Angry Birds Star Wars who have also Twitter accounts got the chance to post the info of their favorite characters on Twitter. Unfortunately we do not have any tool to disconnect Twitter from our game at the moment. However, you can use the 'manage account' option in Twitter app and remove your account on Twitter before your children start playing the game, or disable the internet connection on your device.
>
> To log out of your Twitter account, launch the Twitter app and go to "Manage accounts" (it's the button next to the settings button on your Twitter profile page). Then remove your default account. When you wish to tweet again, just log in to the app and you're good to go!
>
> We are still working on developing this feature for future updates, so we apologize for any inconvenience this might cause. Hope you enjoy the game!
>
> Best regards,
>
> Kalle
>
> Rovio Support Team

Comment: Thanks! I sure hope the guys at rovio understand that their suggestion is less than satisfactory, to say the least, and that a feature to disable tweets will be added soon!

Answer (score 0):

In Settings > Twitter, scroll down and there should be a section titled "Allow", under which should be a list of apps with On/Off toggles that you can use to disable their access to your Twitter accounts.

Comment: Angry birds do not appear on the list

Comment: Same here - Angry Birds does not appear on the list of apps - in fact I have nothing listed so can't turn off the tweet option for photos either. So I'm removing the entire access from iOS to Twitter (and dumping the official app too) until integration can be controlled properly.